# ivy generator missing in 2.93?

Tags: interface, add-on

2.93 - enabled the ivygen add-on, and the "generate" tab now appears in the sidebar, but... the tab doesn't do anything. There's no options window when the tab's selected.
(I followed the manual, selected a vertice, snapped the 3d cursor to it, changed to object mode with the object selected...)

Comment: I've not used it before but it seems to work ok in 2.93.5 under Windows 10. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In Object mode, after setting the 3D cursor position, click <kbd>Create</kbd> in the sidebar and you should see <kbd>Ivy Generator</kbd> in the dropdown at the top of the screen:
[image]

If you click that you should see all the settings and clicking <kbd>Add New Ivy</kbd> should spawn your ivy shown below:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!. I doubt I'd ever notice that pull down menu on my own. (t seems that the documentation and tutorials are either inaccurate or tricky to follow.)

Comment: No problem. I just followed my nose! :^)  Please check my answer to accept it.